# Spring 3 & JPA using JTATransactionManager, but transaction manager fails to commit

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, jta

I am using Spring and integrating with hibernate 4 as persistence Provider, here what i ma trying is to do crud operation
on student Entity,

All my select operations are working fine, but add and update operation are not working,

My persistence.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">          
       <persistence-unit name="forSpring" transaction-type="JTA">
        <class>com.entity.Student</class>
       </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My Spring-bean.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"       
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"     
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"   
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />               
<context:component-scan base-package="com.*" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="datasourceId" jndi-name="jdbc/myPrac" resource-ref="true" />
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />

    <!-- Spring integration with JPA -->
<bean id="vendorAdaptor-inj" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database"  value="DERBY"  />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />                    
</bean> 

<bean id="entityMgrFactory-inj" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">         
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasourceId" />       
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="forSpring" />           
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="vendorAdaptor-inj" />
</bean>     

</beans>
```

This is my StudentDAO,

```
package com.dao;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.entity.Student;


@Repository("studentSpringDao-inj")
@Transactional(value="txManager",readOnly=true)
public class StudentSpringDAO {


    @PersistenceContext(unitName="forSpring")
    private EntityManager em;

    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return em;
    }

    public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudentList()  throws Exception{
        System.out.println(" \n\n\n LOADING... \n\n\n ");
        String query = "select s from Student s order by s.studentId desc";
        TypedQuery<Student> studentQuery =  em.createQuery(query,Student.class);
        return  studentQuery.getResultList();
    }

    public Integer latestStudent()  throws Exception{
        String query = "select max(s.studentId) from Student s";
        TypedQuery<Integer> studentQuery =  em.createQuery(query,Integer.class);        
        return  studentQuery.getResultList().get(0);
    }

    @Transactional(value="txManager",readOnly=false,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Student saveStudent(Student student) throws Exception{           
        return em.merge(student);
    }
}
```

Just for the information, i am using jndi look-up name "jdbc/myPrac" to look-up the datasource,

Can you help me out with this, do i am missing any configuration in spring-bean.xml

Answer (score 1):

```
@Transactional(value="txManager",readOnly=true)
```

What do you think `readOnly=true` means and have you tried it with `readOnly=false`?

Comment: Ok, the problem is even my EntityManager instance in StudentDAO is Null , canu tell me what should be the problem

Comment: You said your select works fine. How can they work fine if your EntityManager is null?

Comment: when i entered the <tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="txManager" /> in spring-bean.xml, my entityManager is not null, fetching students works, but unable to do merge operation, insert query doesn't gets fired ,

Comment: i did readOnly=false in @Transational, than too the merge operation don't work

Answer (score 0):

replace the class `org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager` 
with `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager` and add `tx:annotation-driven`